# Excluir quebras de linha em um echo no PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma página html/php que recebe dados em um textarea e salva em um banco mysql.

Às vezes o usuário utiliza quebra de linha em seu texto e salva no banco de boa.

Tenho também uma página php que converte um registro qualquer em json,  https://buscafree.com.br/listaDetalhe.php?id=1, que pode ser lido por um app android que estou desenvolvendo.

Porém, quando tem alguma quebra de linha, o app dá problema na leitura do json.

Se clicar no link acima, verá que o valor da chave `descricao` está assim: `Tudo em moda masculina. Os melhores preços você encontra aqui! Venda via Instagram.` Aqui não mostra, mas depois da exclamação, existe uma quebra de linha antes do texto 'Venda via Instagram'. Não está fácil de resolver, pois não sei como "pegar" essa quebra de linha

Como fazer em php pra ignorar a quebra de linha em um banco mysql ao gerar um `echo`, exemplo:

```
echo semQuebraDeLinha($linha['dado']);
```

Comment: Tentou `$v = str_replace("\n"," ", $linha['dado'])` ou `preg_replace('/\s/',' ',$string);`

Comment: @RBZ, não funcionou visto que as quebras de linha não são salvas no banco por \n

Comment: Então remove no select com `replace`... tentou ?

Comment: Utilizei a função nl2br() que acrescentou no texto armazenado no BD MySQL o texto com diversos <br />. Mesmo assim, próximo a estas quebras, ainda persistiam quebras de linha... então, em seguida a função acima, utilizei o str_replace(), fazendo a troca das quebras - char(10) - por <br>... o texto então ficou armazenado com duas quebras de linhas <br /> e <br>, uma próxima a outra, significando que mesmo utilizando a função nl2br, ainda persistia uma quebra de linha tipo chr(10)... para retornar o texto à tela com apenas uma quebra por linha, utilizei o str_replce para retirar um dos <br>.

Comment: Veja essa outra também. Substituindo o char(10)...

Comment: Vc tentou preg_replace assim: `preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $linha['dado'] );`

Comment: a questão é que o texto aparece normal, sem nenhum símbolo indicando a quebra de linha :/

Comment: adicione a pergunta como fica o texto

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam adicionado

Comment: @RBZ acho que deve funcionar com o char(10), mas não estou entendendo como usar. pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: No mysql ele aparece 2 "quadrados" estranhos. Eu já fiz uma pergunta e coloquei uma imagem disso. Estou no celular, não consigo testar agora, mas amanhã testo e te falo.

Comment: desculpa pessoal, resolvi com a dica do @FabianoMonteiro: preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $linha['dado'] ); Se quiser receber os pontos é só postar a resposta. abraço

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, tente realizar uma pesquisa por uma expressão regular e a substitui, limpando `\r` retorno de carro (“carriage return”) e `\n`  Newline. 
Veja:

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $linha['dado'] );
```

Se a correspondência for encontrada, o novo subject($linha['dado']) será devolvido, caso contrário subject será devolvido inalterado ou NULL se um erro ocorreu. fonte: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)